# Transforming XML to XSLT not working in IE 11

Tags: xml, xslt

I am using IE 11 and trying to fix an application which was working before. It still works in Chrome.
The XML is being returned from a stored procedure, but the xslt is not being able to process it. Here is the code in .js file:

```
function completeReview(data) {
    xml = data.responseXML;
    xsl = asyncLoadXSLT('../Styles/XSLT/MyXslt.xslt');
    transformXSLT(xml, xsl, "CommentContainer");
    $("#txtComment").val('');
}

//Transform results
function transformXSLT(xml, xslt, containerID) {
    $('#' + containerID).html(" ");
    // code for IE for client side xsl transformation
    if (window.ActiveXObject || xhttp.responseType == "msxml-document") {
        ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
        $('#' + containerID).html(ex);
    }
```

The code errors out at

```
ex = xml.transformNode(xsl);
```

the error says:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'transformNode'.
```

I am not sure where the issue is. I tried making the xslt compatible with previous version of IE by introducing-

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
```

in the xslt file, which didn't help. 
I have done it as:

```
<xsl:template match="DATA">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE9" />
<xsl:for-each select="Comment">
...
```

Not sure how to include it though.
Please guide what necessary steps should I take to resolve this issue.

Comment: We need to see the relevant code, the `xml` variable you have is set as `data.responseXML` but you haven't shown the code creating the `data` object and making the request. If `data` is an `XMLHttpRequest` object, make sure for IE you set `data.responseType = 'msxml-document'` before making the request.

Comment: Also you might want to explain in more detail whether code worked before in IE versions before IE 11 but never worked with IE 11 or whether it worked before in IE 11 and has stopped doing so. In the latter case you might want to explain what has changed. As for the `meta`, you would to put that into the HTML document using the script code you have shown, not into the XSLT or HTML generated by the XSLT.